# MySQL Query Not Working on new phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I may have found a bug?

I'm trying to select values where the time is after or 10 minutes before the current time.

Query with the new phpmyadmin
[image]

EXACT same query with EXACT same database but with old phpmyadmin

[image]

- The databases are IDENTICAL, I exported from the new phpmyadmin to the old one.
- There is an hour between the databases, though (new one being with my hosting). But even then, the results showed are greater than an hour.

Here's the query if anyone wants to test

```
SELECT times.lastloggedin 
FROM times 
WHERE times.lastloggedin >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE 
ORDER BY lastloggedin
```

Or I can provide the table for you to test on your own database

I also forgot to mention that these queries are being run within a few seconds of each other too, so they're accurate

Comment: if you are using two different servers then NOW() giving you different datetime

Comment: @tzafar The `SELECT` clearly states `10 MINUTE` but is going back hours..

Comment: check this `SELECT NOW()` on your both phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem was with my hosting time being back many hours and I had `>=` so anything greater than the time was showing!